# Grouping data by location and OS Type

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a query that return the following results:

```
    Location      OS         Count
    AB02        Windows 7     42
    AB02        Windows 7     2
    AB02        Windows 7     1
    AB02 - SW   Windows 7     36
    AB02 - SW   Windows 10    62
```

How would I combine this data to get the following?

```
    Location      OS         Count
    AB02        Windows 7     81
    AB02 - SW   Windows 10    62
```

I tried GROUP BY LEFT(Location, 4), OS but that doesn't return what I need. I need to combine the OS and the Location, AB02 and AB - SW are combined.

Here is my query:

```
    SELECT MIN(Location) AS Location
    , CASE WHEN OS LIKE '%Windows 7%' THEN 'Windows 7' 
    WHEN OS LIKE '%Windows 10%' THEN 'Windows 10'
    ELSE OS END AS OS
    , COUNT(OS) AS 'Count'          
    FROM ComputerProperties
    GROUP BY LEFT(Location, 4), OS
    ORDER BY Location
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: The results you are expecting aren't grouped by Location and OS type. Clearly in the sample you have 36 count at location AB02 - SW for Windows 7. Those records don't appear to be in your results.

Comment: can you show us the query you wrote ?, what kind of DB it is and what version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select OS, sum(Count) as count 

FROM
(
     your existing query
) 
as x

group by OS
```

Comment: I modified the above query and got it to work. Thanks for pointing out that I needed a nested SELECT. I'm learning. Thank you.